# Install a Python module without the package name in setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I have the following project tree:

```
project/
   |-pkgOne/
   |   |- ...
   |-pkgTwo/
   |   |- ...
   |-classes/
   |     |-__init__.py
   |     |-MyClass.py
   |     |-MyOtherClass.py
   |-setup.py
```

I wonder if there is a method to install my classes in a way that prevent this import form:

```
from classes import MyClass
```

But instead:

```
import MyClass
```

Currently, I'm installing my classes this way in `setup.py` (with `setuptools`):

```
py_modules=["classes.MyClass", "classes.MyOtherClasses", ...]
```

But after installation, I have to import my classes with the first method (by including the package name).

Thank you !

Comment: Why not just place the `MyClass.py` one level up in the `project` dir?

Comment: The project will quickly grow in size, with more and more classes, and other scripts will eventually come to the `project/` dir level. That would be a mess.

Comment: Why I'm asking is because your project structure looks unclean to me - you're declaring a package `classes`, but trying to pretend it doesn't exist. If it doesn't bother you, I'd probably go with installing a `pth` file that explicitly adds `classes` to `sys.path` so one can import from `MyClass` module directly.